# Do I have to code utility methods for Spring/Hibernate bidirectional associations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I read this [Thorben Janssen's topic](https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-for-many-to-many-associations-with-hibernate-and-jpa/) about Best Practices for Many-to-Many Associations with Hibernate and JPA.

There, Janssen said that a bidirectional association requires **utility methods**, as written below:

```
@Entity
public class Author {
 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<Book>();
 
    ...
     
    public void addBook(Book book) {
        this.books.add(book);
        book.getAuthors().add(this);
    }
 
    public void removeBook(Book book) {
        this.books.remove(book);
        book.getAuthors().remove(this);
    }
}
```

Does Spring/Hibernate provide any @Annotation to solve this problem automatically?

By the way, take a look at [Thorben Janssen's topic](https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-for-many-to-many-associations-with-hibernate-and-jpa/).

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: There does not to be an annotation for this. If you want to, you can write such an annotation yourself. However, the performance is better when you add the code manually because such an annotation might need the reflection API.

"**Need for utility methods**": These utility methods help with synchronising both sides of the relationship, i.e. if you add an `Author` to a `Book`, you will also have to add the `Book` to the `Author`. You do not need to have these utility methods and you can add the objects to each other manually. However, these utility methods avoid failures as the synchronisations happens automatically.